# Is there anyway to use qt creator and qt 3d studio for python and pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-creator, python-3.7

I want to use qt creator and qt design studio and qt 3d studio for pyqt5
Is there anyway to I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed PyQt5 via pip, those tools were removed. So in ordered to get them you need to install the PyQt5 Tools package -> https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/